# HTML Page Title in Excel VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

Given an url, how can I get the title of the html page in VBA in Excel?

For example suppose I have three urls like :

- http://url1.com/somepage.html
- http://url2.com/page.html
- http://url3.com/page.html

Now I need to get the title of these html pages in another column. How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by title, but here is an idea:

```
Dim wb As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim sURL As String

Set wb = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

sURL = "http://lessthandot.com"

wb.Navigate sURL

While wb.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

''HTML Document
Set doc = wb.document

''Title
Debug.Print doc.Title

Set wb = Nothing
```

Comment: By title, I meant the content within the <title></title> tag of the html page. I will try your code out.

Comment: @redGREENblue that is what you will get from the above.

Answer (score 7):

Remou's answer was VERY helpful for me, but it caused a problem: It doesn't close the Internet Explorer process, so since I needed to run this dozens of times I ended up with too many IEs open, and my computer couldn't handle this.

So just add

```
wb.Quit
```

and everything will be fine.

This is the code that works for me:

```
Function GetTitleFromURL(sURL As String)
Dim wb As Object
Dim doc As Object

Set wb = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

wb.Navigate sURL

While wb.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

GetTitleFromURL = wb.Document.Title

wb.Quit

Set wb = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use Selenium :

```
Sub Get_Title()
Dim driver As New WebDriver
debug.print driver.Title
End Sub
```