# Excel VBA to get website Title from url

Tags: excel, vba

[HTML Page Title in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625316/html-page-title-in-excel-vba/14509576#14509576)

I know that this is fairly old but I'm having difficulty with this. I've built a browswer history parser that goes through the history data from Firefox, IE, Safari, and Chrome on our users computers (Office) and then it gets titles for pages that don't using this code.

I get popups from IE even though it should be hidden. Do you want to leave this page, download popups, install this ActiveX this or thats that I have to close out as they come up.

Is there a way to suppress those or automatically close those from VBA? If I don't do it by hand the computer/Excel eventually stops working as I end up with several unclosed IE windows or it errors out because it can't open anymore IE instances.

Plus I feel pretty sick knowing that IE is opening sites that I don't know anything about. We have more infections in this office than I have ever had to deal with before. We have to use IE for the company software to run on.

Is there a better way of doing this or are we just victims of the system. I'm just awestruck at how little can actually be done in MS Office VBA compared to OOo BASIC. At least basic feature wise (redimensioning arrays, FTP support).

Please for the love of monkeys let there be a better way.

I've also tried....

```
Function fgetMetaTitle(ByVal strURL) As String

Dim stPnt As Long, x As String
Dim oXH As Object
'Get URL's HTML Source
Set oXH = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
With oXH
    .Open "get", strURL, False
    .send
    x = .responseText
End With
Set oXH = Nothing
'Parse HTML Source for Title
If InStr(1, UCase(x), "<TITLE>") Then
    stPnt = InStr(1, UCase(x), "<TITLE>") + Len("<TITLE>")
    fgetMetaTitle = Mid(x, stPnt, InStr(stPnt, UCase(x), "</TITLE>") - stPnt)
Else
    fgetMetaTitle = ""
End If

End Function
```

And this one.....

```
Function getMetaDescription(ByVal strURL As String) As String

'Requires Early Binding Reference to MSHTML Object Library
Dim html1 As HTMLDocument
Dim html2 As HTMLDocument

Set html1 = New HTMLDocument
Set html2 = html1.createDocumentFromUrl(strURL, "")

Do Until html2.readyState = "complete": DoEvents: Loop

getMetaDescription = html2.getElementsByTagName("meta").Item("Description").Content

Set html2 = Nothing
Set html1 = Nothing

End Function
```

Nether have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Works fine for me in MS Excel 2010

```
Dim title As String
Dim objHttp As Object
Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.google.com/", False
objHttp.Send ""

title = objHttp.ResponseText

If InStr(1, UCase(title), "<TITLE>") Then
    title = Mid(title, InStr(1, UCase(title), "<TITLE>") + Len("<TITLE>"))
    title = Mid(title, 1, InStr(1, UCase(title), "</TITLE>") - 1)
Else
    title = ""
End If

MsgBox title
```

Comment: +1. Note: if behind a proxy, you may have some trouble with this approach as it doesn't automatically use IEs proxy settings.

Comment: I added code to check for the http and added it if needed and presto... You sir are a saint.

Comment: I am running into an issue of wonky characters in the titles that are returned. Good means of stripping all but maybe ASCII?

Comment: Have a string with accepted symbols, then loop through the title character by character and make a compare with the string.