# Unable to convert my existing scraper to xmlhttp request

Tags: vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I have written a script to get Title from any random websites. It works flawlessly. I have written this using Internet Explorer. I've tried a lot but can't make the same using xmlhttp request as performance is a big issue to consider. What I've tried so far is:

```
Sub Title_scraping()
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As Object, cel As Range

For Each cel In Range("A1:A5")
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.navigate cel.Value

    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set doc = IE.document
    x = x + 1
    Cells(x, 2) = doc.title
Next cel
End Sub
```

Sites I've tried with and got results:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
https://yts.ag/browse-movies
```

Comment: A quick search in SO gives [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514181/excel-vba-to-get-website-title-from-url)

Comment: Thanks Tehscript, for the link. This is what I wanted. Btw, could you combine the answer here so that I can accept it? I have already created one applying split function on responsetext. Not finalized yet, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining your code and the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514181/excel-vba-to-get-website-title-from-url), here is your final code:

```
Sub GetData()
Dim title As String
Dim objHttp As Object, cel As Range, x As Long
Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

For Each cel In Range("A1:A5")
    objHttp.Open "GET", cel.Value, False
    On Error Resume Next
    objHttp.send ""

    title = objHttp.responseText
    If InStr(1, UCase(title), "<TITLE>") Then
        title = Mid(title, InStr(1, UCase(title), "<TITLE>") + Len("<TITLE>"))
        title = Mid(title, 1, InStr(1, UCase(title), "</TITLE>") - 1)
    Else
        title = ""
    End If
    x = x + 1
    Cells(x, 2) = title
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tehscript, for your robust solution. You saved my day.

Comment: @SMth80 Happy to help!