# Generate Webpage Titles from List of URLs in Excel

Tags: vba, url, excel, title

I have a column in Excel of website URLs and would like to automatically retrieve the webpage titles for each of those URLs and place them in a second corresponding column.

I don't have any experience with VBA, but would like to use VBA to do this. Can someone please list the steps one-by-one to get this done? What code do I paste and where? How do I point the code to the right column  to pick up the URLs and how do I tell it where to populate the results? How do I run the code?

I think this is a popular problem but many don't uses the existing documentation on how to address it because they have the same issue as me -- they don't know how to load and run the script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Googling gives me quite a few hits for this, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625316/html-page-title-in-excel-vba or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514181/excel-vba-to-get-website-title-from-url  Try using one of those approaches, and post back with your code if you run into problems.

Comment: I pasted that code into a module but I don't see a way of telling it which column to read and which column to input into. And when I run the code, nothing happens. That's why I was hoping for a play-by-play for those not savvy with VBA

Comment: Any advice on how I tell it which column to read (which column contains the domain names) and which column to output into (the resulting titles? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Adjust the range "A1:A10" to match your data....

```
Sub GetTitles()
    Dim c As Range, url As String
    For Each c In Range("A1:A10").Cells
        url = Trim(c.Value)
        If LCase(url) Like "http://*" Then
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = GetTitle(url)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

Function GetTitle(sURL As String)
    Dim title As String, res As String, pos1, pos2
    Dim objHttp As Object
    Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHttp.Open "GET", sURL, False
    objHttp.Send ""

    res = objHttp.ResponseText
    pos1 = InStr(1, UCase(res), "<TITLE>")
    pos2 = InStr(1, UCase(res), "</TITLE>")

    title = "<not found>"
    If pos1 > 0 And pos2 > 0 Then
        pos1 = pos1 + Len("<TITLE>")
        title = Mid(res, pos1, pos2 - pos1)
    End If
    GetTitle = title
End Function
```