# How to find the title of an URL using VBA in MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am working on a VBA project to get Page title and created date from an URL. I found this code online but it's not working since IE is not available. Is there any way I can get the title without IE?

```
Function GetPageTitle(a As String)

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate a
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    GetPageTitle = .document.Title
    .Quit
End With

End Function
```

I have tried to use Edge as Internet Explorer but it's not working.
I have tried this code also [HTML Page Title in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625316/html-page-title-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Could you share the link to the webpage and the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

### Get Webpage Title

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetPageTitleTEST()
    Const URL As String = "https://www.google.com"
    Dim PageTitle As String: PageTitle = GetPageTitle(URL)
    If Len(PageTitle) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print PageTitle
    Else
        Debug.Print "Nope."
    End If
End Sub

Function GetPageTitle( ByVal URL As String) As String
    Dim Response As String
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .Open "Get", URL, False
        .send
        Response = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .body.innerHTML = Response
        GetPageTitle = .getElementsByTagName("title")(0).innerText
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'GetPageTitle' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: I tried this on a Mac and it seems to return nothing, no error message, just nothing when I try different URLs. Would you expect this to work on Mac (with no Internet Explorer, etc.)? I have a URL in A1 (say the URL of this question's page). Then in A2 I do `=GetPageTitle(A1)`, return, and the A2 cell looks empty. But it's not, since I can this the equation in the formula bar when my cursor is above the cell. Any help with this? I have little experience with VBA and UDFs.

Comment: Works like a charm -- Skips the browser-automation methods altogether... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I followed this other post here [Excel VBA using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205408/excel-vba-using-selenium) after following the instructions by @Yu Zhou. I was receiving the error about the chrome binary not being found. I switched "edge" to "chrome". Basically, the post says you need to download the correct chrome version from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. And then install it (for Windows users) here `C:\Users\ *Username\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic`. You need to overwrite the old chrome driver.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to automate Edge with VBA, you need to use **SeleniumBasic**. SeleniumBasic is a Selenium based browser automation framework for VB.Net, VBA and VBScript.

You can follow the steps below:

1. Download the latest version of SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.0 from [this link](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0) and install it.
2. Download the corresponding version of Edge WebDriver from [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).
3. Find the path of SeleniumBasic which is `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic` in my computer (it might also be in this path `C:\Program Files\SeleniumBasic`), copy the Edge WebDriver `msedgedriver.exe` to this path.
4. Rename `msedgedriver.exe` to `edgedriver.exe`.
5. Open Excel and write the VBA code.
6. In the VBA code interface, click **Tools > References**, add **Selenium Type Library** reference and click **OK** to save.
7. Sample VBA code to automate Edge using SeleniumBasic to get URL title:

```
Public Sub Selenium()
        Dim bot As New WebDriver
        bot.Start "edge", "https://www.bing.com"
        bot.Get "/"
        bot.Wait 5000
        Debug.Print bot.Window.Title  'this line of code can get title
End Sub
```